# Como captar qualquer botão através do OnClick?

Tags: android, onclick

Tenho dez Buttons no meu XML e quero que mude o Text do botão que o usuário clicar.

Eu implementei um View.OnClickListener no meu Activity e o meu onClick ficou assim:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        button.setText("X");
    }
```

Não deu certo.
Sou obrigado a criar um switch para cada Button?
Não há como usar um único código para todos os botões?

Comment: Veja se essa resposta no SOen ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282194/1377664

Comment: De acordo com o link acima sou obrigado a criar um SetOnClickListener para cada botão ou verificar um por um através do id.

Comment: Pode especificar o que deu errado? Pois o que vc fez funciona sim.

Answer (score 0):

Em seu XML você pode utilizar o atributo `onClick` para que todos eles façam uma chamada ao método de clique.

> XML

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
    ...
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
    ...
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>
```

> Activity

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonOne: { break; }
        case R.id.buttonTwo: { break; }
        case R.id.buttonThree: { break; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira você pode economizar algumas linhas de código. Outra coisa, dependendo de quais funções os botões da sua tela possuem, você também pode utilizar uma **RecyclerView**, que também te economizará muito código. Mas isto vai depender da função exercida por cada botão, se elas forem *muito diferentes*, acredito que você que usar o exemplo do código mesmo, mas se chegarem no mesmo **fim**, você poderia utilizar uma **RecylerView**.

Por exemplo, se tu deseja abrir uma tela pra cada botão, você poderia utilizar a **RV** e dependendo do botão clicado, retornar um **Bundle** para abrir a tela correspondente, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, tinha quase certeza que isso é algo que é possível fazer sim. Fiquei com aquela pulguinha atrás da orelha, e resolvi testar rapidinho. O resultado foi que ambos os botoes ficaram com o texto "Clicked!" quando clicados.

**Meu XML**

```
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**Na Activity**

```
this.button.setOnClickListener(this)
this.button2.setOnClickListener(this)

 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    var button = v as Button
    button.text = "Clicked!"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemente View.OnClickListener na sua Activity, no metodo onClick faça

Lembre de setar os botões

Button bt = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
bt.setOnClickListener (this);

```
Public void onClick (View view) { Button tmp = (Button) findViewById (view.getId ()); tmp.setText ("Funciona");}
```